# XCode 4 only displaying cout statements with endl

Tags: c++, xcode4, cout, endl

I have a really weird issue with my cout statements. I've only tried this out with XCode 4. For instance, if I write,

```
cout << "this works" << endl;
cout << "this doesnt";
cout << memorySizeLimit << " blocks of memory available." << endl;
```

I see all three output statements in my debugger console. However, if I change the order to,

```
cout << memorySizeLimit << " blocks of memory available." << endl;
cout << "this works" << endl;
cout << "this doesn't";
```

I only see the first two couts. Even stranger, if I change the code to,

```
cout << memorySizeLimit << " blocks of memory available." << endl;
cout << "this works" << endl;
cout << "this doesn't" << endl;
```

I see all three statements.

Why would I not see that "this doesn't" cout statement when I change its position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::cout` is an stream and normally it is buffered for performance. If you print `endl` the stream gets flushed (`cout << endl` is the same as `cout << "\n" << flush`.

You may flush the stream manually by `cout << flush` (or `cout.flush()`).

So that should print:

```
cout << "this doesn't" << flush;
```

Comment: ditto :) FWIW, this is normal stream behaviour, not Xcode specific

Comment: Thanks - I've just never run into this issue before. Pardon the awkward phrase, but I'll remember to flush now!